# TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'rowType'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

gettting TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be
used to index type 'rowType'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on
type 'rowType'.
error on this row  {rowData[key]}

```
import * as React from "react"

interface  rowType {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  title: string;
  completed: boolean;
}

export interface RowProps { rowData: rowType};

const Row = ({ rowData }: RowProps) => {

  return (
      <>
          {Object.keys(rowData).map((key:) =>(
              <div> {rowData[key]}</div>
          ))}
      </>
  )
}

export default Row;
```